# How to use Gronwall's inequality?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities

I am  just trying to understand the role of Grownwall's Lemma  to show global wellposedness results, in the paper I have been reading. And So I hope this is OK for MO.

---

Let $u\in C(\mathbb R, L^{2})$ and $\|f\|_{\mathcal{F}L^1}= \|\hat{f}\|_{L^1}$, and we denote  $ \mathcal{F}L^{1}=W.$

Put $w(t)= \sup_{0\leq \tau \leq t} \| u(\tau )\|_{W}.$  We suppose that,

for any $T>0,$ and $0< \alpha ' < \infty,$ we have,

$$w(t)^{\alpha'} \lesssim 1 + \int_0^{t} w(\tau)^{\alpha '} d\tau .$$

Then [the paper page no. 6](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.3615.pdf)  I have been reading tells that, by Gronwall lemma:
 $w\in L^{\infty}([0,T])$

My Question is: How to justify this?

My Vague Idea: To apply [Gronwall Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_with_locally_finite_measures), I need to show that $w(t)^{\alpha'}\in L^{1}(0, T)$. But I do not know how this follows.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the authors want to say the following:

Define 
$$
Y(t)=1+\int_0^t w(\tau)^{\alpha'}d\tau.
$$

Then your inequality reduces to
$$
Y'(t)\leq Y(t),
$$
so Gronwall inequality (differentiated form) implies
$$
Y(t)\leq Y(0)e^t
$$
and $Y(t)\in L^\infty$, which means that $w(t)\in L^1$. Another application of Gronwall inequality (integrated form) now implies a point wise bound for $w$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks: But why $Y(t)$ is differentiable?  Don't we need the differentiability hypothesis in [Gronwall Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Differential_form). Thanks